# GNU MAKE: functions in dependencies

Tags: makefile

I would like to generate a number of files using GNU Make using the following recipe.

```
ina_as%.dat:       ina_driver.m    ina_as$(word 1,$(subst _epsi, , %)).m
     echo "modelType = '$(word 1,$(subst _epsi, , $*))'; ofile = '$@'; epsi = '$(word 2,$(subst _epsi, , $*))';" | cat - $< | nohup matlab -nodesktop -nosplash
```

The targets are in a format -- ina_as%d_epsi%.2f.dat (e.g. ina_as1_epsi0.50.dat) and the second prerequisite is ina_as%d.m (e.g. ina_as1.m) (notice, the second part _epsi%.2f missing in the prerequisite file name).

I have tried several combination for the implicit rule ($*, $$*, $(eval $*) etc.), but it still does not work. I think it could be because Make could not understand the functions ( '$(word 1,$(subst _epsi, , %))' ) in the dependency definition.

There is any way to overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Questions like this come up from time to time. The short answer is that Make simply can't do this in a clean way; the text manipulation statements expand before executing any rule (i.e. before `%` has any value), and Make doesn't handle wildcards (or regular expressions) very well.

The longer answer is that it can be done, but only by resorting to one kludge or another. If your version of Make supports SECONDEXPANSION, you can do it this way:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

ina_as%.dat: ina_as$$(word 1,$$(subst _, ,%)).m
    @echo "modelType = '$(word 1,$(subst _epsi, , $*))'; ofile = '$@'; epsi\
  = '$(word 2,$(subst _epsi, , $*))';" | cat - $< | nohup matlab -nodesktop\
  -nosplash
```

If not, you can resort to recursive Make (useful sometimes, no matter what they say):

```
ina_as%.dat :
    @$(MAKE) dummy MODELTYPE=`echo $* | sed "s/_.*//"` EPSI=`echo $* | sed \
  "s/.*_epsi//"`


dummy: ina_as$(MODELTYPE).m
    @echo "modelType = $(MODELTYPE); ofile = ina_as$(MODELTYPE)_epsi$(EPSI)\
  ; epsi = $(EPSI);" | cat - ina_as$(MODELTYPE).m | nohup matlab -nodesktop\
  -nosplash
```